# How to ignore code tag contents with html-minifier-terser

Tags: sveltekit, terser

The problem happens when I use text editor on admin part of website with enabled prerender mode.
html-minifier-terser dies when it meets contents of <.code> tag

What could be a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

`ignoreCustomFragments: [ /<code>(.|\n)*?<\/code>/ ],`

did the trick